# Why is this still returning a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, promise

I have a function to get an attribute from a PostgreSQL table using node-postgresql.

```
const { Client } = require("pg");

const client = new Client();
client.connect();

const query = (text, params) => client.query(text, params);

const inArray = (arr, el) => (arr.indexOf(el) > -1);

const isValidTable = table => {
  const options = ["users", "photos", "comments", "likes"];
  return inArray(options, table);
};

const isValidColumn = (table, col) => {
  if (!isValidTable(table)) return false;
  const options = {
    users: [
      "id",
      "username",
      "password",
      "email",
      "name",
      "avatar_id",
      "created_at"
    ]
  };
  return inArray(options[table], col);
};

const getAttribute = async (table, col, id) => {
  if (!isValidColumn(table, col)) return;
  const q = `
    SELECT ${col}
    FROM ${table}
    WHERE id = $1
    LIMIT 1
  `;
  const params = [id];
  const res = await query(q, params);
  return res.rows[0][col];
};

// Returns Promise<Pending>
const att = getAttribute("users", "username", 1);
console.log(att);

// Returns the attribute
(async () => {
  const att = await getAttribute("users", "username", 1);
  console.log(att);
})();
```

Why when I call this function I still get a promise, even though I have Async/Await? Also, any suggestions on how to improve this code?

Comment: `even though I have Async/Await` async functions *always* return promises. async/await simplifies the syntax for working with promises, it doesn't eliminate them.

Comment: you can't make async code synchronous.

Comment: The function returns a promise *because* you use `async`(`await`).

Comment: In that case, since the query function already returns a Promise, then there is need to use async/await unless I am changing the output of that function inside getAttribute(), correct?

Comment: @etts, a big benefit of an AsyncFunction is that it is guaranteed to throw asynchronously even from synchronously executed code. So if, for example, the expression `isValidColumn(table, col)` throws, then the Promise returned by `getAttribute()` would reject and make the error available on its fail path. Callers of AsyncFunctions can thus catch errors with whichever mechanism they choose, regardless of whether they are themselves AsyncFunctions or Functions; ie `try{} catch(err){}` and `.then().catch()` are both guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

asfopoo is partially right, but I think it's more accurate to say that when async functions are called from synchronous code you get a promise. If you want to log the value returned from an async function, write `asyncFunction().then( (value) => { console.log(value);});`. `.then()` will run after your async call completes.

Answer (score 0):

await returns a promise, .then() gets the value from the promise

```
(async () => {
  await getAttribute("users", "username", 1).then(response => {
  console.log(response);
}})();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Async functions always return a Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), even though your `getAttribute` code appears to return an attribute value.

> **Return value**
>
> A Promise which will be resolved with the value returned by the async function, or rejected with an exception uncaught within the async function.